# #selector's with local functions

Tags: swift

I'm building this app to display restaurants around my hometown and give them a menu, time of opening, and address. I have this function here to display info about the restaurant in the collection view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantCollectionViewCell

    cell.addressLabel.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = restaurantArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.openingTimeLabel.text = openingTimeArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.chosenRestaurantButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getProducts), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

This is the function that I pass to the #selector in the collection view function. The thing is that I need the index path from the collection view function in the getProducts function. I can't nest the functions it throws an error about local functions. Any way I can get the index path in the getProducts function?

```
func getProducts() {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productsCollectionView") as! ProductsViewController
    viewController.restaurantChosen = restaurantArray[indexPathVariable.row]
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the indexPath to your button handler. You can determine the indexPath from the button itself.

First, update your button handler to include the button as the parameter:

```
func getProducts(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Then you can calculate the indexPath from the button's position inside the collection view.

```
let position = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: collectionView)
let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: position)
```

Here's your complete method:

```
func getProducts(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let position = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: collectionView)
    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: position) {
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productsCollectionView") as! ProductsViewController
        viewController.restaurantChosen = restaurantArray[indexPath.row]
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This code assumes that `cell.chosenRestaurantButton` is a `UIButton`. It also assumes your view controller has a `collectionView` property.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do something like this with buttons within reusable cells. Why don't you just use a delegate in your RestaurantCollectionViewCell subclass?

```
protocol RestaurantCollectionViewCellDelegate: class
{
    func getProducts(indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class RestaurantCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    var indexPath: IndexPath!
    weak var delegate: RestaurantCollectionViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.delegate?.getProducts(indexPath: self.indexPath)
    }
}
```

And in your CollectionView controller simply assign the delegate like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, RestaurantCollectionViewCellDelegate
{
    func getProducts(indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productsCollectionView") as! ProductsViewController
        viewController.restaurantChosen = restaurantArray[indexPath.row]
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCVCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantCollectionViewCell
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - your code is using a text field delegate but the question is about a UIButton.